# Read redirect file from web server (.txt file) and verify response from page ("MalformedURLException: no protocol")

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

First time posting, but have used this site more times than I can recall!  I'm very new to programming and I've been tasked to write automated test scripts with `Selenium WebDriver`, which has ultimately lead me to learning some basic (to some) Java.

What I'm attempting to do is read a text file(a large file of redirects) that resides on a web server, loop through each line, and finally check the response from the page (which I haven't really coded yet).  I have created a script that loads each page and asserts it's not a `404`, but I'm looking for a solution that will be MUCH faster by *hopefully* just testing the http response.

The lines in the text file may appear in the following formats:

**myredirect http://www.example.com/apage.html** //a url external to the host

**anotherredirect /apage.html** //single space between the redirect and the destination path, no protocol/host

**andanotherredirect  /apage.html** //two spaces between the redirect and the destination path, again no protocol/host

I'm getting the following failure:

> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol:

I appreciate any assistance!

```
public class RedirectTestFireFox {
WebDriver driver;
StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();


@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testRedirectTestFireFox() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    //read redirects from file on web server
    URL test = new URL("https://www.example.com/redirects.txt");

    //get the protocol (http or https)
    String protocol = test.getProtocol();

    //get the host of the supplied url
    String host = test.getHost();

    //create baseURL variable that appends protocol "://" and the host
    String baseURL= protocol + "://" + host;

    //do something to each URL in text file
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(test.openStream())){
        //while there is still another line in the redirects file...
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {

            //assign value to "line" variable
            String line = scan.nextLine();

            if(line != null){

                String redirect = line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" "));

                //find the last instance of a space and then take what is to the right of that and assign it back to line variable
                line = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf(" ")+1, line.length());

                //trim off any blank spaces from either end
                line.trim();

                //test to see if the first character starts with "/"
                boolean firstChar = line.startsWith("/");

                //if firstChar is "/" append the baseURL variable to the redirect
                if(firstChar) {
                    line = baseURL + line;
                }

                URL u = new URL(line); //this is the where it fails!!!
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection =(HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection (); 
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();
                try {
                    int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
                    assertEquals(200, code);
                } catch (AssertionError e) {
                    System.err.println("Error found! " + redirect);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    }

@After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Selenium is definitely the **wrong** tool for this. Try something like curl, wget, httpbuilder, etc.